# Pymongo sort comments in descending order

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

In a small blog application I'd like to sort comments according to date in descending order. Newest comments will be top.

A typical post looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : 15,
    "title" : "Soup making techniques",
    "content" : "In this tutorial we'd like to share best soup making practices.",
    "updatedate" : ISODate("2017-10-19T21:13:19.193Z"),
    "comments" : [
        {
            "content" : "This is my first comment.",
            "_id" : 25,
            "date" : ISODate("2017-10-19T21:13:31.328Z")
        },
        {
            "content" : "Another comment.",
            "_id" : 26,
            "date" : ISODate("2017-10-19T21:29:36.536Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Also on python side the relevant code looks like this;

```
post = document.find_one({'_id': int(number)}, sort=[("comments.date", -1)])

result = document.find_one( { '_id' : int(number) , "comments": { '$exists': True, '$ne': False } })

comments = []
commentlist = []

if result:
    commentlist = post['comments']
    print ("All comments", commentlist)

    for comment in commentlist:
        comments.append({'commentid' : comment['_id'], 'date' : comment['date'], 'content' : comment['content']})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things worth mentioning with regard to the schema design you posted:

1. If one post have a lot of long comments, it can plausibly be over 16 MB in size, which is the size limit of a MongoDB document.
2. Putting comments in an array makes it hard to sort, as you have discovered.

The Python script you posted is forced to extract the comments array and insert them into a temporary document one-by-one to get it into a sorted order. I don't imagine this approach will be performant. You have at least a couple of options to avoid doing this:

1. Insert a new comment at the beginning of the array so that the array is always sorted in descending order. This can be achieved using `$push` with the `$position` modifier (see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)
2. Put the comments on a separate collection, with reference to the original post. This makes it easily sortable, with the tradeoff of a relatively more complex retrieval (but it can't be worse than the current script you have).

Depending on your use case, either option 1, 2, or both might be applicable to you.

You might also want to take a look at storing comments use case: https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-comments/